# Add extra data for ajax call of typeahead.js remote option

Tags: typeahead.js

I'd like to ask how I could add extra params for the AJAX call made by `remote` option. I have following simple form to search for qualification (it's in Coffeescript):

```
$('#search_qualification').typeahead
  name:  'qualification'
  limit: 50
  remote:
    url: "/search/qualification?term=%QUERY"
```

I'd like to send another param with the AJAX call, that is `state`, normally with jQuery AJAX call, I'd do this:

```
$.ajax
  url: "/search/qualification"
  dataType: "json"
  data:
    term: request.term
    state: $("#state").val()
```

I am totally clueless in adapting this for typeahead.js, can someone please help me out here? Many thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the `replace` option:

```js
$('#search_qualification').typeahead({
  name:  'qualification'
  limit: 50
  remote: {
    url: '/search/qualification?term=%QUERY&state=%STATE'
    replace: function(url, query) {
      var state = encodeURIComponent($('#state').val());

      return url.replace('%QUERY', query).replace('%STATE', state);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Any downside in not using `replace` and simply modifying the `url` to accommodate any extra parameter e.g.  `/search/qualification?term=%QUERY&state='+encodeURIComponent($('#state').val());`